# mongodb lookup aggregation result different in Mongodb Compass and shell

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working on a $lookup aggregator
on Mongodb using the below code, it works fine with all the fields which I required but which I worked with a shell the return files of lookup table are less,

```
{
  from: 'dreg',
  let: {id:"$_id"},
  pipeline:[
    {$match:{$expr:{"$eq":["$ownerId", "$$id"]}}},
    {$project:{
    _id:0,
    dSRN:1,
    dom:1,
    dor:1,
    dos:1,
    storageLimit:1,
    dDSN:1
  }}],
  as: 'devices'
}
```

shell

```
db.cmst.aggregate([
    {$match:{owner:ObjectId('5f70b14023dded214c3d1680')}},
    {$project:{
        _id:0,
        clientName:1,
        cuid:1,
    }},
    {$lookup:{
        from: 'dreg',
        let: {id:"$_id"},
        pipeline:[
          {$match:{$expr:{"$eq":["$ownerId", "$$id"]}}},
          {$project:{
            _id:0,
            dSRN:1,
            dom:1,
            dor:1,
            dos:1,
            storageLimit:1,
            dDSN:1
        }}],
        as: 'devices'
    }}
])
```

return in shell only three fields we are getting :

```
dom,
storageLimit,
dSRN
```

Comment: Your query in shell seems weird to me that you are dropping your `_id` field in the second `$project` stage but you are using it for `$lookup` later. Are your sure this is expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes you are right changing the _Id:1 it works , but it works in mongoDb compass ,

Comment: You will need to provide sample data, expected output. For your case, it will be helpful that you provide the difference between the result of shell and compass

Comment: @user3529042 ever solve this?